# How to Read Json data using php when json object send by android?

Tags: php

I want to store data in my mysql database  which is send from android through         webservice. I cant understand how to access fields value  from json..

json format is like this:

```
{'User_Usr':[
  {
 "id": 912345678901,
 "text": "How do I write JSON on Android?",
 "geo": null,
 "user": {
   "name": "android_newb",
   "followers_count": 41
 },
 {
  "id": 912345678902,
  "text": "@android_newb just use android.util.JsonWriter!",
  "geo": [50.454722, -104.606667],
  "user": {
   "name": "jesse",
   "followers_count": 2
  }
 }
  ]}
```

So plz. send me solution of this problem..
Thanks in advance.....

Comment: Try google man, this is really simple.

Comment: @PozzoApps: Dude you havnt understood my question... i just wanted to know the correct  format of json... i resolved it on my own.. thanks for your this type of valuable suggestion..

Answer (score 2):

You can refer detail information on  http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php

```
$json = '{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}';

var_dump(json_decode($json));
var_dump(json_decode($json, true));
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
$value = json_decode(jsonString);
```

Here `$value` is an array that holds value of `jsonString`.
Process this array to store the value in the database

Answer (score 0):

Use the PHP function json_decode(); It will convert the json data to PHP data, so as this is being passed as a class `due to being wrapped in { and }` $t elow will be an object.
Best to just do a print_r(t) on the result and that will show you what is being generated.

```
$t = json_decode($android_data);
print_r($t);
```